# charAt looping with the first 2 numbers can t loop it

Tags: java, string, char

```
import cs1.Keyboard;

public class charAT {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s;

        //The telephone number should be 79575757
        System.out.println("Enter your telephone number");
        s = Keyboard.readString();

        int index1 = s.charAt(0);
```

This part does not work:

```
        if((char)index1 == 7){
            System.out.println("The second number is "+(char)index1);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("This number is invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no loop in this example.

Comment: Your question is entirely unclear, please describe what you are trying to do with your code and, preferably, what you think is expected behaviour of the code you've written, and where that mismatches what really happens. Also, your code contains several basic mistakes. You may want to look deeper into some tutorials on java basics first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, charAt() method returns `char`, so your code should be like this:

```
char ch = s.charAt(0);
```

I changed the variable name from `index1` to `ch`. charAt() method returns the `char` at the specified position, not an index.

Second, you should compare the `char`:

```
if (ch == '7') {
```

And the last, you can concatenate `String` and `char` like this:

```
System.out.println("The second number is "+ ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that you are checking index1 against the integer value 7. Change that to

```
char index1 = s.charAt(0);
if(index1 == '7'){
```

Next, I'm assuming you want to get the second number, not just display the same one again, so

```
    index1 = s.charAt(1); //get the second character
    System.out.println("The second number is "+ index1);
}
```

Comment: method String.charAt(int) returns a char. Storing it in an int only to cast it to a char again later makes no sense at all.

Comment: I know. Just trying to keep as much as I can of the code the same. But I'll edit to use `char` instead, since it does make more sense.